# In Google Sheets Query Max Date from Dates in Column A for a particular Project ID stored in Col B in Tab 'Data' from Tab 'Main'

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

Tab Data is as under

```
Date_A       Project_ID
01-May-18   EL-PR-18-08709-1
02-May-18   EL-PR-18-08709-1
01-May-18   EL-PR-18-08709-1
03-May-18   EL-PR-18-08709-1
02-May-18   EL-PR-18-08709-1
01-May-18   EL-PR-18-08709-3
04-May-18   EL-PR-18-08709-3
03-May-18   EL-PR-18-08709-3
05-May-18   EL-PR-18-08709-3
05-May-18   EL-PR-18-08709-3
30-Apr-18   EL-PR-18-08709-2
01-May-18   EL-PR-18-08709-2
02-May-18   EL-PR-18-08709-2
```

I want to Query Max(Date_A) based on a particular Project ID and want to place it in Tab Main, I have tried `=Query(Data!A1:B12,"Select max(A) where B='EL-PR-18-08709-1'",1)` but it gives `Parse error`.

I understand that Max cannot be used with where clause.

Comment: Maybe the cause of the problem is the regional settings of your spreadsheet causing that you should use `;` as parameter separator instead of  `,`.

Comment: For me, the query formula is working as well. It's perfectly possible to use MAX and WHERE clauses together in a QUERY(). Maybe share your spreadsheet so that we can debug the problem further.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> =ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
>    SORT(filter('Data'!$A$2:$A, 
>     'Main'!$B$2:$B='EL-PR-18-08709-1'), 
>    1,FALSE),1,1)
> ```

I would simplify your formula to:

```
=MAX(FILTER(Data!$A$2:$A,    
   Main!$B$2:$B="EL-PR-18-08709-1"))
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your comment, Ruben. Actually `,` as a parameter separator is working nicely on my computer, so that is not the issue. Query function does not permit to use Max and where together in a query. Anyhow, I could find another way to extract the Max date as per my criteria by the following formula `;`

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORT(
 filter('Data'!$A$2:$A,'Main'!$B$2:$B='EL-PR-18-08709-1'),1,FALSE),1,1)
```

I am writing this formula in Tab Main in the cell where I want this Max date.

Comment: "Query function does not permit to use Max and where together in a query." Not true. It must be something else.